# Calculate time difference in 24 Hours format with date

Tags: javascript

I'm working on Airline API. I came across a situation where I have to calculate the flying time of the airline.

```
Standard Departure Time is 2014-10-20 22:30:00

Standard Arrival Time is >2014-10-21 06:00:00
```

The flight departs by 10:30 PM on Oct 20 2014 and arrives at 6:00 AM the next day.

Is there a working snippet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate time differences if you convert your dates to timestamps, which are int values.

pseudocode example: timestampDiff = dateToTimestamp(date2) - dateToTimeStamp(date1)

in javascript:

```
var timestampDiff = new Date("2014-10-21 06:00:00").getTime() - new Date("2014-10-20 22:30:00").getTime();
var diff = new Date(timestampDiff);
```

diff is now a Date, you can get the hours, minutes, seconds like this:

```
diff.getHours();
diff.getMinutes();
diff.getSeconds();
```

hope this helps.